# Can I distinguish native from hybrid Apps?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone, multi-device-hybrid-apps

the question is up in the heading. 
Can I distinguish a native App from a hybrid App when I download it from the Google Play Store?

Can someone link to any App in the Google Play Store that is for sure Hybrid?

I am new to this field, so sorry if it may sounds too easy but I researched online and I couldn't find an answer.

thanks

Comment: refer this link https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/extract-android-apk-view-source-code/

Comment: point 2  Extracting the source from a hybrid Android application

The source code of hybrid applications are by far the easiest to extract.  You don’t need any extra software installed on your computer, just access to the APK file.

Comment: I think we didn't know the app is native or hybrid when we upload into any store, for suppose if you want to upload an application in playstore you have to upload android application. So that is native app.There is no store to store hybrid apps.

Comment: yes we can predict but not 100% sure.like android app having back button on top right corner( for support iphone need to add back button) while you do scroll it won't be smooth scrolling. hybrid app on playstore developed by me https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.comprider.hello&hl=en

Comment: thanks, gonna try it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following method - go to Settings > Developer Options and check the "Show view bounds" button. Then, the bounds of views will be shown everywhere. But, if you open HTML/JS hybrid app, you will not see any bounds, as there is only one view - the WebView.

P.S. To enable the Developer Options, go to Settings > About Device and start clicking on Build Number.

P.P.S. You can find some other cool stuff in developer options, too.

Comment: Thanks. I think this one is the right answer for question.